# Image from PDF using ZendFramework

Tags: php, image, zend-pdf

is there any way to save a PDF as an image using ZendFramework? I'm still looking for a solution with good performance. I've heard of ImageMagick, but the performance sucks and it's hard to configure the output properly for special needs (e.g. different sizes and DPI).

Greets dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework alone will not help you in this case.

But ImageMagick is rather easy to use as a command line:

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=230074